# Unable to see new activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I mean to make an app with a "settings" button, that will create a new activity when pressed. I want that new activity to show the actual settings page.

Here's the XML code of the Settings button:

```
<Button
android:text="Settings"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/buttonResSettings" />
```

Here's the code where I call the new activity, which is in my main activity's `OnCreate`:

```
Button resSetButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonResSettings);
resSetButton.Click += delegate {
var ResSetAct = new Intent(this, typeof(ResSettingsActivity));
ResSetAct.PutExtra("res", res);
StartActivity(ResSetAct);
};
```

Here's the code of my new activity:

```
public class ResSettingsActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set the view to ResSettings(.axml)
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ResSettings);

        //Fetch the data of the variables
        string res = Intent.GetStringExtra("res");

        //Map the elements of the view to usable objects
        EditText CurRes = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editCurRes);

        //Display the current values of the settings
        CurRes.Text = res;
    }
}
```

Building and using the rest of the app in the emulator poses no problem, but when I click on that Settings button, nothing happens (except the default onClick button design change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remember to add the `[Activity]` Attribute to your new Activity class:

```
[Activity(Label = "Res Settings")]
public class ResSettingsActivity : Activity 
{
    ...
}
```

The attribute will add an entry in the AndroidManifest.xml for you at build time. You can verify this by looking in the obj/Debug/android folder where you can see the resulting manifest. You should see an entry like:

```
<activity android:label="Res Settings" android:name="md51237869127761dfsa77sadvfb.ResSettingsActivity" />
```

If you don't want the name to have a md5 sum prefixed you can add the `Name` property to the Activity Attribute:

```
[Activity(Label = "Res Settings", Name = "my.package.name.ResSettingsActivity")]
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up ! The problem persists, though.

Comment: I resolved it by changing `var ResSetAct` into `Intent ResSetAct`, after a suggestion of Parveen Prajapati.

Comment: That shouldn't really change anything

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent theintent = new Intent(A.this,B.java);
theintent.putExtra("name",john);
startActivity(theintent);
```

Also declare the class `b.java` in the manifest file.

Comment: if button will not work then add onclick property in button xml

Comment: Thanks ! I just changed the `var ResSetAct` into `Intent ResSetAct`, added what Cheesebaron mentionned. Now it works like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityTwo.class);  

// Set the request code to any code you like, you can identify the  
// callback via this code  
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
```

You can pass an intent like this and declare class `DisplayMessageActivity` in manifest-file.